# localhost project link not working

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I'm completely new to PHP and I'm trying to get started.

I have my WAMP server installed and I have my subfolder in the www file ( "/workingthroughthebook" ) but when I run my localhost page and try to click on the Your Projects link, it tells me the web page is unavailable and I also notice it changes the director to just "/workingthroughthebook" with nothing else before it.

Are there any easier to understand documents on the internet or very thorough videos I could read or watch that can explain what I need to do to get the "Your Projects" links to work properly? - Or could anyone comment on what I need to do?

There are a few very lengthy articles I've found that rush their explanation which are probably made for people who understand everything that's in them, but this is all completely new to me.

My goal is to be able to understand what it is that I'm doing exactly rather than just copying and pasting and changing a few details here and there, and I would like to understand what I'm doing with each step I take.

**tl:dr**

I'm using WAMP 2.5. The W icon is green and my localhost page shows up. I'm just having issues with the project links and I'm trying to get some sort of grip on this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Please, remember that this is all new to me so I'm trying to get used to the syntax of it all and I don't know the terms for everything yet.

Comment: This post should help you understand why and how to make it work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: A good idea would to build a variable with the base root or directory of your current workspace. So you can use that variable and build links with it. This way when you move hosting locations or domains the links rebuild themselves.
`$base_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'; 
echo $base_url . 'any/folder/path/whatever';`

Comment: That seems like it's definitely what would fix my problem, but I ran into another problem. I'm on windows 8.1 and they don't give the admin permission to modify the system files. Now I have to figure out how to change that, but thank you! Your response and the link you gave me are extremely useful and I look forward to trying them out as soon as possible.